# migration from thorntail to quarkus maven dependencies scope

Tags: quarkus

We will be migrating our services from thorntail to quarkus.

With thorntail, we define the scope of io.thorntail dependencies as *provided* in our dependency modules. In the module where the uber jar is built (war packaging), we set the default *compile* scope. We apply this rule because we were facing thorntail crashes during startup. We started to apply this rule from thorntail version 2018.06.

Do we need to apply the same rule with quarkus? Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just add the dependencies as normal compile dependencies.